How does the optimization landscape relate to the vanishing/exploding gradient problem in deep learning?
I'm trying to fully understand why the vanishing and exploding gradient problems are so detrimental to training deep neural networks. I understand that these problems result in some weights having very small gradients (vanishing gradient) and others having very large gradients (exploding gradient).
To visualize this, I imagine a 3D cost function with parameters/weights  and  on the X and Z axes, and the cost on the Y axis. If the gradient with respect to  is larger than  (due to an exploding gradient), I expect a steep ravine along the X axis near the optimum. Conversely, if the gradient with respect to  is smaller than  (due to a vanishing gradient), the Z axis would have a shallower slope near the optimum.
In this scenario, the core issue seems to be that the learning rate wouldn't be able to accommodate both parameters effectively. A learning rate suitable for  (where the gradient is large) would cause instability for  (where the gradient is small), and vice versa.
This brings me to my main question: it seems that the 'expected ratio between the gradient of the cost with respect to the parameter and the distance to the optimum' should ideally be the same for all parameters. This way, a single learning rate could be effective for all parameters.
Is this understanding correct, and is there a specific term or concept that describes this ratio? Does this explain why vanishing/exploding gradients cause problems in training?
Edit: If anyone's interested, after doing some reading, I found that this concept relates to the second derivative. Second-order optimization methods take this into account. The second derivative provides information about the curvature at the current point, which gives us information about how fast we're flattening out (or not), allowing us to take a more precise step.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
